# JAVASCRIPT REGEX for digits suite

Tags: javascript, regex, digits

Is there a way to use regex to check if an array contains exactly one occurence of each number in a range ?

`myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

I have tried this :

`let regex = /[1-9]{1}/;`

But this only checks that the array contains at least one occurence in the range : )

Comment: I don't think regex is the right approach for this. Better loop over the array and check

Comment: isn't `/[1-9]{1}/` better written `/[1-9]/`

Comment: Don't know why you want it done with regex but [`^(?!.*\b(\d+)\b.*\b\1\b).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/qJJ7ht/1/) should work

Comment: thanks for the replies, Hao, would you mind walk me through your answer?

Answer (score 2):

The described validation is not a particularly good use case for regex.

One alternative way to find the answer you seek is to:

1. Create a Set with the array items. (A Set by default only retains unique values.)
2. Convert the Set back to array.
3. Compare the lengths of the original array and the new array. If they mismatch, the difference is the number of array items that exist in duplicate.

```
// return TRUE if myArr only has unique values
[...new Set(myArr)].length === myArr.length
```

Comment: or just `new Set(...).size`

Comment: Of course Set is the way to go, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just filter for duplicates and compare the original array with the filtered to see if it had any duplicates. Upside here is that you can use the filtered array if you need it

```js
let myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5]
let uniques = myArr.filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i)
let hasDupes = myArr.length != uniques.length
console.log("hasdupes?", hasDupes);
console.log(uniques)
```

Comment: thanks Kinglish, I like this syntax, although I was trying to find a simpler way to do it :)